# error: the application has failed to start because mspdb100.dll was not found

Tags: windows-xp, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I am running a software which compile some codes based on VC++,
I have installed Visual studio 2010 professional on my XP professional windows.
whenever I wanna execute the Compile "the application has failed to start because mspdb100.dll was not found." comes up.
any ideas?

---

I added the path directory to PATH environment variables;
another error came up: cannot open include file:"string.h": No such file or directory;

Comment: Did you check if `mspdb100.dll` is located in here?: `%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\mspdb100.dll`

Comment: yes,i have checked.it is there,even I set environment for vs2010

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have noticed when we just add "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin " every time system restarted you gotta do the same process,otherwise we would face such error"the application has failed to start because mspdb100.dll was not found" for example in executing cl.exe

Instead I did add "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE" into my environment variables and I can run all C++ based programs.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

it seems [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990331/ms-c-2010-and-mspdb100-dll) might have a solution for you